# Table with "repeat header" option off

Tags: r, flextable, officer

I'm inserting a `flextable` into `.docx` with `add_body_flextable`. How can I switch off "repeat header" option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No option for that, acording to package author (see GitHub issue #160: https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/160)